# LSTM and CNN: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (400, 256)

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I want to apply `CNN` and `LSTM` on my data, I just choose a small set of data; My training data's size is `(400,50)`and my testing data is `(200,50)`. 
With only CNN model, it works without any errors, I just  have many errors when adding the LSTM model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=8,
                 kernel_size=16,
                 padding='valid',
                 activation='relu',
                 strides=1, input_shape=(50,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,strides=None, padding='valid', input_shape=(50,1))) # strides=None means strides=pool_size
model.add(Conv1D(filters=8,
                 kernel_size=8,
                 padding='valid',
                 activation='relu',
                 strides=1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,strides=None, padding='valid',input_shape=(50,1)))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
              activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
              dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2)) # 100 num of LSTM units
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
              activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
              dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
              activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
              dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
              activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
              dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
              activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
              dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(256, activation='softmax')))

# # # 4. Compile model
print('########################### Compilation of the model ######################################')
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
print('###########################Fitting the model ######################################')
# # # # # 5. Fit model on training data
x_train = x_train.reshape((400,50,1))
print(x_train.shape) # (400,50,1)
x_test = x_test.reshape((200,50,1))
print(x_test.shape) # (200,50,1)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=100, epochs=100,verbose=0)
print(model.summary()) 
# # # # # 6. Evaluate model on test data
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print (score)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CNN_LSTM_Based_Attack.py", line 156, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=100, epochs=100,verbose=0)
  File "/home/doc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 853, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/doc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1424, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/home/doc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1304, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/home/doc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 127, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (400, 256)
```

You can find here the whole summary for this model:(I am new with LSTM it is the first time that I use it).

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 35, 8)             136
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 17, 8)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 17, 8)             0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 10, 8)             520
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1 (None, 5, 8)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 5, 8)              0
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 5, 32)             5248
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 5, 32)             8320
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 5, 32)             8320
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 5, 32)             8320
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_5 (LSTM)                (None, 5, 32)             8320
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, 5, 256)            8448
=================================================================
Total params: 47,632
Trainable params: 47,632
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

When I replace this lines of code:

```
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
              activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
              dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2)) # 100 num of LSTM units
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
              activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
              dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
              activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
              dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
              activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
              dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
              activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
              dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(256, activation='softmax')))
```

With only this line:

```
model.add(LSTM(26, activation='tanh'))
```

Than it works very well.

I would be grateful if you could help me please.

Comment: Please post the error message

Comment: @JonasAdler  I am sorry I forgot to put the error. I have edited my post.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are trying to do... What is the output shape of the last MaxPool?

Comment: @bluesummers  thank you for  your commen, It is about 
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1 (None, 5, 8)

Comment: So how does this (None, 5, 8) gets unrolled through the lstms? can you show the output.shape of the first and last lstns?

Comment: Can you post the output of the model summary? One thing that is different of the LSTM that "works" is that you don't return the entire sequence - is this on purpose?

Comment: @niklascp I edited my post I put all the table summary for my  model.

Comment: @bluesummers  I edited my post I put all the table summary for my model

Comment: @tierrytestu: ok, thanks- see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So LSTM layers expect input in shape (Samples, Time steps, Features). When stacking LSTM you should return_sequences = True. This will give an output of shape (Samples, Time steps, units), thus allowing the stack to fit together - You should set return_sequences = False on the last LSTM-layer if you only want to predict one step ahead (i.e. the next value in the sequence/time series) - if you don't it will predict the same number of time steps as is in the input. You can of cause also predict a different number (e.g. given 50 past observations predict the next 10, but it is a little tricky in Keras).

In your case the Conv/MaxPool-layers output 5 "time steps" and you have return_sequences = True on the last LSTM-layer - so your "y" must have shape (Samples, 5, 256) - otherwise turn return_sequences = False on the last layer and don't use TimeDistributed, as you only predict one time step ahead.